# Fatal Error: FetchRow

Tags: php

i'm an a newbie in programming, i am a sys admin but sometimes i need to fix same php pages when i have to migrate them from/to another web server.
I'm working on an old website with an old php verson (5.3.8), it works more or less but i have a problem in php log:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function FetchRow() on a non-object in 297

Line 297 = `while( $row_colore = $rs_colori->FetchRow() ){`

Line 296 = `$rs_colori = $db->Execute("select * from colori where id_prodotto = ".$_REQUEST['id_prodotto']." order by descrizione");`

How can i fix it?

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: looks like the query failed

Comment: Your query failed. Check for mysql errors after the execute. Here's how to check [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rs_colori = $db->Execute("select * from colori where id_prodotto = '".$_REQUEST['id_prodotto']."' order by descrizione");
```

I think the problem is coming from concatenation issue combined with the quotes you tried to use inside the query which causes the query to "break". Give a try to this query.

Comment: Glad i helped !

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function FetchRow() on a non-object**
means that your query does not return an object, it failed for one reason or another, so to debug the issue, try to print (echo) your query before executing it.